# .map() , Undefined is not a function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

So I make a call to a API and use it to setState.

My state:

```
  state = {
   candlesticks: []
};
```

My API call and promise function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
    "apiurl"
      )
      .then(data => {
        let mappedData = data.map((record) => {record.date *= 1000}); //getting the error here with the map()function
        this.setState({
          candlesticks: mappedData
        });
      });
  }
```

I've tried different variations on the code but it still gives this error.
I'm using Expo framework.

> undefined is not a function
>    (evaluating 'data.map(function (record){record.date *= 1000})')

Comment: Probably you have to parse the `data` from the response. That could be something like `data.body.map` or `data.content.map`. Print `data` to see what it really contains!

Comment: I have used this same data on the web before so I know. However I used jQuery then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios returns a [response](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#response-schema) object. Inside the response you have a data property with your data.
So what you need to do is:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("apiurl")
    .then(response => {
        let mappedData = response.data.map((record) => {record.date *= 1000}); //getting the error here with the map()function
        this.setState({
            candlesticks: mappedData
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit**

Doesn't seem possible that there's a problem with axios, but just to rule it out, try to use the built-in [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) module and see if the data is still null.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch("apiurl")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
     })
    .then(data => {
        let mappedData = data.map((record) => {record.date *= 1000});
        this.setState({
            candlesticks: mappedData
        });
    });
}
```

If it's null then the problem is in your server.

Comment: I was aware of the response object this was a silly error. thank you.

Comment: The data returned from the response object is all `null` though.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: This same map method and data worked when I was using with jQuery on the web before.

Comment: The data is returned correctly when the map() method isn't applied.

Comment: I found out I had to return the data for it to work.

Comment: But then it seems its not mapped fully

Comment: this is the api url https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_BCN&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=86400

Comment: I checked it out , I want to return the full object with the date updated.